# Autopopulate Foreign Key Field Based on User Choice Selection

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have two models:

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    entity = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=12)
    entityDescription = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.entityDescription

class Action(models.Model):
    entity = models.ForeignKey(Entity, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='entity')
    entityDescription = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    action = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.entity
```

I have a model form and model formset, along with a form helper for crispy-forms:

```
class ActionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Action
        fields = '__all__'
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AlertForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
        if instance and instance.pk:
            disabledFields = ['entity',
                              'entityDescription']
            for field in disabledFields:
                self.fields[field].disabled=True
        else:
            self.fields['entity'].blank=True
            self.fields['entityDescription'] = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Entity.objects.all())

ActionFormSet = modelformset_factory(Action, extra=1, exclude=(), form=ActionForm)

class ActionFormsetHelper(FormHelper):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ActionFormsetHelper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.form_method = 'post'
        self.template = 'bootstrap/table_inline_formset.html'
        self.add_input(Submit("submit", "Submit"))
        self.layout = Layout(
            Field('entity', css_class="input", type="hidden"),
            Field('entityDescription', css_class="input"),
            Field('action', css_class="input")
        )
```

I have a view:

```
def actions(request):
    newActions = Action.objects.filter(action='')
    formset = ActionFormSet(request.POST or None, queryset=newActions)
    helper = ActionFormsetHelper()
    context = {'formset':formset, 'helper':helper}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for form in formset:
            if form.is_valid():
                if form.has_changed():
                    obj = form.save(commit=False)
                    obj.entity = form.cleaned_data['entityDescription']
                    obj.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/actions')
    return render(request, 'actions/actions.html', context)
```

So my rendered page looks something like this:

```
entityDescription    action
Jim Halpert          [Blank Cell]
Michael Scott        [Blank Cell]
[Blank Cell]         [Blank Cell]
```

`entity` is hidden, and `entityDescription` is driven by the `Entity` model. When the user selects an entityDescription, I would like `entity` to be autopopulated in the `Action` model. Logically, this means `entityDescription` would need to go back to the `Entity` model, find the corresponding `entity` primary key, and place that value in the `entity` foreign key in the `Action` model.

My attempt at this is in the view. I saved the form without committing,  tried to assign some value to `entity`, then attempted to commit the form. This attempt results in this error:

```
Cannot assign "<Some Entity Description>": "Action.entity" must be a "Entity" instance.
```

This makes sense, because I tried to just assign the `entityDescription` to `entity` instead of assigning the `entity`. I next tried to just get the `entity` in a hacky manner since it is the first word in `entityDescription`:

```
obj.entity = form.cleaned_data['entityDescription'].split(' ', 1)[0]
```

This resulted in the same error, despite `entity` looking correct in the error. These errors are occurring for both the existing model formset members AND the new member.

How do I retrieve the primary key of the `Entity` model when the user selects a value from the `Entity` model? Then how do I assign that primary key to the corresponding foreign key field in the `Action` model?

**Edit:**

[image]

So Jim and Michael are existing records in `Action`. The user can assign them an action. The blank line is a new action. The user can choose the `entityDescription` from the `Entity` model. `entity` is a hidden field (i.e. 1 for Jim, 2 for Michael).

When the user selects an `entityDescription` for the new line (i.e. user selects Jim), the primary key (1) should be entered into the hidden `entity` field prior to saving the forms.

**Another Edit:**

After further investigation, if I implement the solution in the provided answer, the problem is here:

```
obj.entity = Entity.objects.get(pk=pk)
```

This is actually returning the `entityDescription` of the `Entity` model (i.e. what is defined by `def __str__`) rather than the primary key. I attempted to change this to...

```
obj.entity = Entity.objects.get(pk=pk).entity
```

...but this results in the primary key being returned as a string rather than an object. Therefore it can't be saved to the database. How would I go about turning this string into an object? In other words, how do I use the query language to get one value from one field from one object of a Django model?

Answer (score 0):

Your `obj.entity` should assign as *object*, and `form.cleaned_data` isn't return as object.

try to print what the output of this, If I following your case, makesure it as `id/pk` from the selected entity:

```
print(form.cleaned_data['entityDescription'])
# eg: 16
```

Then:

```
obj.entity = form.cleaned_data['entityDescription']
```

should be;

```
pk = form.cleaned_data['entityDescription']
obj.entity = get_object_or_404(Entity, pk=pk)
#            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this is object instance

# OR

pk = form.cleaned_data['entityDescription']
obj.entity = Entity.objects.get(pk=pk)
#            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this is object instance
```

Comment: So `entity` is actually the pk of the `Entity` model. How would I return `entity` rather than `entityDescription`? The user is selecting `entityDescription`, but I want `entity` to be placed in `entity` in the `Action ` model.

Comment: `pk = form.cleaned_data['entityDescription'].split(' ', 1)[0]` works for existing members of the model formset, but when the user is entering new information (i.e. has to enter BOTH `entityDescription` and `action`) it still doesn't work. 

Logically, I need to use `entityDescription` to query the `Entity` model and return the actual pk object (`entity`).

Comment: you can use `Entity.objects.get_or_create(pk=pk)`

Comment: That results in this error: `Cannot assign "(<Entity: SomeEntityDescription>, False)": "Action.entity" must be a "Entity" instance.`

Comment: what exactly you need to do in this case? can you provide a screenshot? and why you has two `entityDescription` fields?

Comment: The `entityDescription` field in the `Action` model might not be necessary. Basically I need the user to select an `entityDescription`. Then I want to retrieve the primary key of that `entityDescription`. Then I want to assign that primary key to the corresponding foreign key `entity` in the `Action` model. Does that make sense? A screenshot will be difficult, but I will see if I can make it work.

Comment: I added a rough screenshot and explanation. Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: I'm okay with the `.split(' ', 1)[0]` method - it just doesn't work for new forms. No error is returned, it just redirects the page without saving the form to the DB.